# System.Windows.LayoutCycleException in a silverlight application?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, exception, silverlight-4.0

I'me currently developing a silverlight application.

In this application,  I've an exception handler which catch every uncaught exception in the app(this is set on the App.xaml.cs:

```
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
```

I've a problem, everythime I click on a specific button(this button just call a method which is supposed to create a user control, put it in a tab and select it), the UnhandledException event is thrown and I receive a "System.Windows.LayoutCycleException", without any stacktrace, and the message "Cycle de disposition détecté. Impossible d'achever la disposition" (english trad: "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete.", this is the error 4008 on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189020(v=vs.95).aspx ).

I've several weird things now:

- if I put a breakpoint on my click event, and I follow the things, the last call I've is the return of a Converter which return true, so I really don't see what can be wrong here
- I've a development server where we have the same version, and I can do the actions
- I've clean the cache a lot of times, tried every browser I've(chrome, Firefox, IE 8, IE 9)
- The user control is displayed a little moment before the exception(in fact, when I have the exception, the user control is displayed)
- Every other actions on the application is working(and there is a lot of other actions possible)
- I've nowhere a LayoutUpdated event

It just makes one day I'm on this problem, I'm going to be crazy if it continues, so every help, tip, ... would be very appreciated.

This is a silverlight 4 application, which run on an asp.net 4.0 /IIS 7.5

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I just saw that I've a more recent version of the Telerik UserControls( Telerik silverlight 2011 Q1) than on my server (Telerik Silverlight 2010 Q3 SP1). I installed this older version on my computer and now it seems to work!